# Bootstrap 5 navigating from menu to respective section on click hides section title

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a single landing page using bootstrap5. Created a navbar a some section.I give the id to the section same as href link in navbar . It redirect to that targeted section as expected but it navbar hides it title[It navigates to our tour section but hides its section title.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kc6S.png)

```
   <header class="fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-center d-flex flex-cloumn" href="#">
        <img
          src="./Images/logo.png"
          alt=""
          width="80"
          height="50"
          class="d-inline-block"
        />
      </a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a
              class="nav-link active"
              aria-current="page"
              href="#"
              >Discover Europe</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#ourtours"
              >Our tours</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#customizedtour"> Customized tour</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#whychooseus">Why Choose Us?</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutus">About Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Please add a [example]

Answer (score 0):

You have `<header class="fixed-top">` - `fixed` positioning does not account for elements below/behind. Judging by your screenshot that seems to be an issue. Change `fixed-top` to  `sticky-top` and it should work just fine.

I made a few snippets which should help.

**Version 1** - `fixed-top` first and the second section is behind the `header`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header class="fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-center d-flex flex-cloumn" href="#">
        <img src="./Images/logo.png" alt="" width="80" height="50" class="d-inline-block" />
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Discover Europe</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#ourtours"
              >Our tours</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#customizedtour"> Customized tour</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#whychooseus">Why Choose Us?</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutus">About Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<section id="ourtours">
  <h1>our tours</h1>
</section>
<section id="customizedtour">
  <h1>customized tours</h1>
</section>
<section id="ourtours">
  <h1>why choose us</h1>
</section>
```

**Version 2** - `sticky-top` first section is directly below `header`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header class="sticky-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-center d-flex flex-cloumn" href="#">
        <img src="./Images/logo.png" alt="" width="80" height="50" class="d-inline-block" />
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Discover Europe</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#ourtours"
              >Our tours</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#customizedtour"> Customized tour</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#whychooseus">Why Choose Us?</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutus">About Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<section id="ourtours">
  <h1>our tours</h1>
</section>
<section id="customizedtour">
  <h1>customized tours</h1>
</section>
<section id="ourtours">
  <h1>why choose us</h1>
</section>
```